# Button Changes the Final Cost/Value

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I've created few buttons, and when clicked I want to affect the final cost, working but not as it should be. The button has a value and the final value of cost doesn't work, can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

```js
function totalIt() {
  var input = document.getElementsByName("product");
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].click) {
      total += parseFloat(input[i].value);
    }
  }
  document.querySelector(".priceText1").innerText = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="priceWrapper">
  <h3 class="priceText1" id="total">$0.00</h3>
  <h3 class="priceText2">Final Cost</h3>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="itemProduct">
    <h4 class="itemText">
      <span class="no_selection">Logos</span>
    </h4>
  </div>

  <div class="itemHidden">
    <form action="" id="theForm">

      <label>
        <button class="buttonBg" name="product" value="25.00" type="button">Producto 3</button>
      </label>

      <label>
        <button class="buttonBg" name="product" value="10.00" type="button">Producto 4</button>
      </label>

    </form>
  </div>
```

But when I pick one, the final price won't work perfectly. is displaying a different number! can some help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the click event to all the buttons and add the cost on every click like the snippet below shows.

**NOTE :** If you want to add the cost just one time by button you could disable the button immediately after the click using :

```
this.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var products = document.querySelectorAll(".buttonBg");

for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  products[i].addEventListener("click", totalIt);
}

function totalIt() {
  var total      = document.querySelector("#total");
  var currentVal = parseInt( total.innerText );
  var new_val    = parseInt( this.value );
  
  if( this.classList.contains('clicked') ){
    total.innerText = ( currentVal - new_val ).toFixed(2);
  }else{
    total.innerText = ( currentVal + new_val ).toFixed(2);
  }
  
  document.querySelector("#total2").innerText = total.innerText;
  
  this.classList.toggle('clicked');
}
```

```css
.clicked{
   color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="priceWrapper">
  <h3 class="priceText1">$<span id="total">0.00</span></h3>
  <h3 class="priceText2">Final Cost</h3>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="itemProduct">
    <h4 class="itemText">
      <span class="no_selection">Logos</span>
    </h4>
  </div>

  <div class="itemHidden">

    <form action="" id="theForm">

      <label>
        <button class="buttonBg" name="product" value="25.00" type="button">Producto 3</button>                      
      </label>

      <label>
        <button class="buttonBg" name="product" value="10.00" type="button">Producto 4</button>
      </label>

    </form>
  </div>
  <h3 class="priceText1">$<span id="total2">0.00</span></h3>
```

Comment: thanks @ZakariaAcharki, I think I understand now, but you can click product infinity of times but should be able to click it just one, if you click it twice it should remove the amount again. that's possible? if not, it keeps adding more amount.

Comment: thanks pal! almost:D but imagine someone includes one product, but then, they decide to remove it, just by clicking again. and if they at the end really want it, clicking a 3rd time to re-include it. so second click should always remove the amount from final price. and 3rd click again to include it again. Make sense ? sorry haha I'm not good explaining myself

Comment: Yes, your explanation was clear, check my update using a flag class then add or remove the amount from the total.

Comment: you're the best!! I'll try to understand it deeply now, but it works really fine:D! thanks. In case I have rendered twice the final price (also in a responsive way in another different total Span. let's say total2, this should work?

var total      = document.querySelector("#total, #total2");

Comment: Glad I could helps bro, Unfortunatly it will not work this way, but you could use simply `document.querySelector("#total2").innerText = total.innerText;`, check my update...

Comment: thanks @ZakariaAcharki you're always very helpful, not sure if you could explain me why this happens, but if I reduce the size of the screen and the box with the <span id ="total2"></> appears only if you select and the deselct a product is when the price appears, is kind of working. Not sure why won't appear. And also, if you select products on regular screen size and you have the result of total1 and then you resize screen and total2 appears it starts from 0 instead of displaying the same amount than total1 with actual selections

Comment: It's really hard to define the problem with low information.. for the second part of your question _total2 appears it starts from 0 instead of displaying the same amount than total1 with actual selections_ I think that because the `total2` will be added to the page dynamically during the resize ... The best choice here is to post a new question with further details about this problem (And let me check it).

Comment: Hello @ZakariaAcharki I've uploaded everything into a jsfiddle page, easier to check. here's the link https://jsfiddle.net/KUBOGRAPHICS/tp392864/

Comment: You've just to adjust the scroll rules take a look to https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/tp392864/4/

Comment: you're definitely the best!!! I'll be checking right now what you did! I need to learn:D! ahaha thanks pal!

Answer (score 0):

I have adapted your code to make this work see below

Note below i have added id's to the product buttons.

```
<div class="priceWrapper">
  <h3 class="priceText1" id="total">$0.00</h3>
  <h3 class="priceText2">Final Cost</h3>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="itemProduct">
    <h4 class="itemText">
                        <span class="no_selection">Logos</span>
                    </h4>
  </div>

  <div class="itemHidden">

    <form action="" id="theForm">

      <label>
        <button class="buttonBg" id="product1" name="product" value="25.00" type="button">
          Producto 3
        </button>
      </label>

      <label>
        <button class="buttonBg" id="product2" name="product" value="10.00" type="button">
          Producto 4
        </button>
      </label>

    </form>
  </div>
```

Then i have modified your code

```
//
// this will be the element clicked so just add it, as below
//
function addProduct() {
  el = this;
  total += parseFloat(el.value);
  total_el.innerText = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
};
//
// Cache your total get a reference to the total element (faster!)
// when you write your code don't keep doing stuff when it can be done
// once - speed is everything and as you write more complex stuff
// doing it write from day one will pay off in your work (toptip)
//
var total = 0;
var total_el = document.querySelector(".priceText1");
//
// Bind up the click event
//
document.getElementById('product1').onclick = addProduct;
document.getElementById('product2').onclick = addProduct;
```

And here you can see the end result

https://jsfiddle.net/64v3n1se/

To scale this you would add the click handler using a class and a loop but for simpleness i have... kept it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Because during your calculation you are getting all button's values and add them up so whenever the button is clicked you calculate the sum of the values of the buttons.

Your way of thinking right now, as far as I can tell, is wrong.

You can change your html code and script code like this.

With this way we are passing object of button to the function and we increase the global total variable within the function. Later on you change the dom.

```
var total = 0;
            function totalIt(obj) {
                total = total + parseFloat(obj.value);
                document.querySelector(".priceText1").innerText = "$" + total.toFixed();
            }
```

And pass the object of button in the html with

```
<button class="buttonBg" name="product" value="10.00" type="button"  onclick="totalIt(this)">
```